# Specification of Electrical Cable List Documentation

Tags: cables, documentation

Up to date, I have found the following specification for building an *Electrical Cable List* in engineering projects for facilities involving electrical and instrumentation equipment and major structures.

- The Cable *DISCIPLINE* can be E: Electrical Power Cables, or J: Instrumentation Control Cables,
- The Cable *FROM* is the equipment delivering the power in the case of Electrical Power Cables, or is the equipment delivering the power towards passive loops in the case of Instrumentation Control Cables,
- The Cable *TO* is the remaining end, accordingly,
- The Cable *TAG* is named according the *TO* Equipment Tag, adding the Discipline Suffix, and adding a Sequential Number (01, 02,...)
- Other field in the Cable List are filled according other specific data, such as facility, location, routed length, specification, voltage level, etc.

I would like to know if anybody have a specific reference supporting this.